# SQL query for matrix resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need kind of a matrix result set. The real case is quite complecated, but the following example will do.

Lets say I have 3 tables:

```
Customers
- ID
- Name

Products
- ID
- Name

Purchases
- ID
- Customers_ID
- Products_ID
- Amount
```

Now, I need a resulset with verticaly the cusomers, horizontaly (as fields) the products and per customer/product the amount sold.

So something like this:

```
Customers.Name&nbsp;Prod#1     Prod#2    Prod#3<br>
Customer #1         10          5       300<br>
Customer #2          5          1        10<br>
Customer #3         50         12        23<br>
```

How can I accomplish this in SQL Server (any version)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pivot

```
select customername,[Prod1],[Prod2],[Prod3] from
(
select c.name as customername,p1.name as productname, Amount from purchases p
left join customers c on p.Customers_ID=c.id
left join products p1 on p.Products_ID-p1.ID
) a
pivot(max(amount) for productname in ([Prod1],[Prod2],[Prod3])) pv
```

Comment: The problem is this part: '([Prod1],[Prod2],[Prod3]'  It seems I'm not allowed to replace this with a sql query.